# Landlord notice to quit when planning to leave

Tags: tenant, fair-housing-acts

I have been living in apartment complex with two other roommates without any issues for two years, paying our rent on time. We were initially on a yearly lease and have since switched to a month to month lease. I was planning on leaving and found a replacement. We have had no issues with replacements in the past and have done it 3 times in the last two years. The landlord this time didn't respond for around a week or so and instead served us a 60 day eviction notice without cause.

The city is not under rent control laws and we are on a month to month lease so the 60 day notice seems legal. However, I was planning to leave and had indicated this in writing to my roommates and my landlord a while back. What are my rights in this case? Do I still have to continue to pay rent if my roommates want to stay to the end of the notice? Do I get my security deposit back? Also, does the notice to quit go on our record if its without cause and we have been paying rent?

Comment: Evictions are court ordered, did you get a "notice to quit"? Or does it really say "eviction"?

Comment: oh it was a notice to quit sorry. i edited the question accordingly

Comment: Are the three of you jointly renting the entire apartment, rather than having separate rental agreements? And the landlord didn't specifically agree to you transferring your lease to someone else in this instance? If that's the case then you're probably all liable till the lease is terminated, although you could still try to sublet for a shorter period.